# rational number solutions to $\frac{a}{a^2+1} + \frac{b}{b^2+1} = \frac{c}{c^2+1}$ with $abc\ne 0$

Tags: diophantine-equations, problem-solving, elliptic-curves, rational-functions, rationality-testing

This question concerns the equation
$$\frac{a}{a^2+1} + \frac{b}{b^2+1} = \frac{c}{c^2+1}$$
and the possibility of rational number solutions with $abc \ne 0$.

In comments arising from: [Using Modularity Theorem and Ribet's Theorem to disprove existence of rational solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466539/using-modularity-theorem-and-ribets-theorem-to-disprove-existence-of-rational-s)
It is mentioned that this equation has an infinite number of such solutions.

How can we determine that there are an infinite number of such solutions?

And is there a way to generate these solutions (or at least find a few of them)?

Comment: If the methods for solving this are generally applicable to rational polynomial functions of rational numbers, please change the title to something more search friendly.  I wasn't sure what to put there.

Comment: Related, lengthy answer here https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-positive-rational-number-solutions-to-the-equation-frac-a-a-2-+-1-+-frac-b-b-2-+-1-frac-c-c-2+1-or-prove-none-exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $C$ be the curve defined by the equation 
$$3(a^2 + 1)(b^2 + 1) = 10( a(b^2 + 1) + b(a^2 + 1)),$$
so rational points on $C$ correspond to solutions of your original equation with $c = 3$. Let $E$ be the elliptic curve with equation
$$y^2 = x^3 + x^2 + 65x + 3458.$$

The point is that $E$ and $C$ are "birationally equivalent" over the rational numbers $\mathbf{Q}$ -- there are maps given by ratios of polynomials with $\mathbf{Q}$-coefficients from $E$ to $C$ and back again, which are well-defined away from a finite set of bad points. (I won't write down the polynomials explicitly; I got the computer program Magma to compute them for me).

Now, elliptic curves over $\mathbf{Q}$ are very well-studied objects, and we can do (or, rather, ask Magma to do) a "descent" computation to find that $E$ has infinitely many rational points and enumerate the first few. Then we just feed them into the map from $E$ to $C$ to get rational points on $C$. This gives the following solutions:
$$ (a, b) = (-627/119, 160/123), (-1287933/7579360, 20097649/13679883), (176228877641067/9078545489689, 14356927982089/53923856957760), \dots $$

If $(a, b)$ is any such solution then clearly $(a, b, 3)$ is a solution to your original problem. So your equation has infinitely many rational solutions.

(I got to this by a little trial and error: I spotted that for a fixed $c$ the equation in $a, b$ gave an elliptic curve, and I tried a few small values of $c$ until I found an elliptic curve with nontrivial rational points. Here is the Magma session:

```
Magma V2.21-4     Thu Oct  8 2015 10:14:42 on fermat   [Seed = 3701259969]
Type ? for help.  Type <Ctrl>-D to quit.
> A<x, y> := AffineSpace(Rationals(), 2);
> S := Curve(A, 3/(3^2 + 1)*(x^2 + 1)*(y^2 + 1) - (x*(y^2 + 1) + y*(x^2 + 1)));
> Sp := ProjectiveClosure(S);
> E, phi := EllipticCurve(Sp, Sp ! [3, 0, 1]);
> Rank(E);
1 true
> _, nu := IsInvertible(phi);
> nu(2*Generators(E)[2]);
> (-627/119 : 123/160 : 1)
> nu(3*Generators(E)[2]);
(-1287933/7579360 : 13679883/20097649 : 1)
```

Try it yourself at the online [Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).
)

PS. One can even write down infinitely many parametric families of solutions: for instance, for any rational $c$ we can take
$$ a = \frac{-c^6 + 3c^4 + c^2 + 1}{c^7 + c^5 + 3c^3 - c}, b = \frac{c^6 - c^4 - c^2 + 1}{2(c^5 + c)}. $$

Comment: This is wonderful! Thank you for the Magma introduction.  How did you get it to produce solutions for arbitrary c?

Comment: I ran those commands, and for E it gave me something different: "Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 - 480*x*y + 3932160*y = x^3 - 250112*x^2 +
14382268416*x - 101584566484992 over Rational Field".   How did you get the elliptic curve you listing there?

Comment: Different Magma versions make different choices of equation for the elliptic curve, but it will still give you the same points on $C$ at the end.

Comment: I still can't figure out how you produced the final equations for $a$ and $b$ for arbitrary $c$.  Did you just put in constant values for c and then try to do some kind of curve fit knowing that it should be a rational polynomial function?  Or is there some easier way?

Comment: I asked Magma to do the same computation as before, but over the rational function field $\mathbf{Q}(c)$ rather than over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: I've spent awhile with the Magma manual and I'm still having trouble. Closest I got was:  Qk<z> := RationalFunctionField(Rationals(),1);
A<x, y> := AffineSpace(Qk, 2);
S := Curve(A, z*(x^2 + 1)*(y^2 + 1) - (z^2 + 1)*(x*(y^2 + 1) + y*(x^2 + 1)));
Genus(S);
Sp := ProjectiveClosure(S);
E, phi := EllipticCurve(Sp, Sp ! [3, 0, 1]);  ... that showed genus 1, but gave the error "Runtime error in '!': Illegal coercion"

Comment: (3, 0, 1) is not a point of S. You want
> E, phi := EllipticCurve(Sp, Sp ! [z, 0, 1]);

Answer (score -2):

-b/(bb+1)=a/(aa+1)-c/(cc+1). Put a=0. Then b/(bb+1)=c/(cc+1). Then b=c. Infinity number of rational solutions. We can replace the problem with -f(b)/f(b)f(b)+1=f(a)/(f(a)f(a)+1)-f(c)/(f(c)f(c)+1) such that f(0)=0 and f is 1:1.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since the OP specifically asked for solutions with $abc \ne 0$.