# Find all rational solutions of $\frac{x}{x^2+4} + \frac{y}{y^2+4} = \frac{z}{z^2+4}$ or show non exist.

Tags: number-theory

Find all rational solutions of the equation:

$$\frac{x}{x^2+4} + \frac{y}{y^2+4} = \frac{z}{z^2+4}$$

else show there are no rational solutions.

Or, generalizing, by replacing 4 with $${w^2},  w>0$$ in the above

$$\frac{x}{x^2+w^2} + \frac{y}{y^2+w^2} = \frac{z}{z^2+w^2}$$

Yields a homogeneous Diophantine equation of 4 variables and degree 5.

So alternatively, show:

$${x}({y^2+w^2})({z^2+w^2}) + ({x^2+w^2}){y}({z^2+w^2}) - ({x^2+w^2})({x^2+w^2}){z} = 0$$

Has no solution in integers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better understanding of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: What work have you done on this?

Comment: Added a bit.  Replacing the constant 4 with a variable transforms problem into a integer problem.  But am stuck at that point.

Comment: There are plenty if obvious solutions, but presumably you mean to say *non-obvious*?

Comment: Yes, for example, x=1,y=0,z=1, w>0 is a trivial example.  We want x,y,x,z > 0 say.

Comment: @AIWicks Substituting $x=2a,y=2b,z=2c$ reduces the problem to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469978/rational-number-solutions-to-fracaa21-fracbb21-fraccc21) (referenced in a previous comment), which I voted as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look!