# Other diophantine equations solved thanks to modularity theorem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

The diophantine equation

\begin{equation}
x^n+y^n=z^n
\end{equation}

is an example of an equation that was not solved before the work of Wiles, and has now been solved through his and other's recent methods. What are other Diophantine equations that were not solved before 1994 and now are, thanks to the modularity theorem?

Comment: I wonder ..  could we say the equation was "solved"? It was proved that there are no integer solutions (n>2), but on the other hand really it is some kind of negative solution..

Comment: Beal's conjecture and the Fermat-Catalan-conjecture are obvious generalizations of Fermat's last theorem, but they are both unsolved.

Comment: There is Denes' conjecture (Ribet), and FLT over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ (Jarvis and Meekin). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537393) and [this paper](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseap/papers/ihpnotes6.pdf).

Comment: See also this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466539

Comment: @Widawensen to me "solving" means presenting with proof the set of solutions (: And the empty set is a set